# Suspended a user on WHM but still receiving chkservd / log still fails

Tags: centos, logging, cpanel, whm

I have suspended a user in WHM, but I am still receiving chkservd hang for that user.

The user's actual access logs in cpanel are not that huge, so I am not sure what's wrong (?)

Answer (score 0):

`chkservd` does not check a specific user.  Rather, it checks specific services (as set in `/etc/chkserv.d/chkservd.conf`) to see if they are running or accessible.

We would be more likely to troubleshoot your problem if you provide relevant logs, but based on the information that you have made available, the emails that you are receiving from your server's cPanel/WHM are an indirect sign of a different problem.

Here are some general items you can check to get you started in your troubleshooting process:

### Useful Log Locations

*These locations can be used to identify an issue that occurred in the past but is not currently occurring.*

- `/var/log/chkservd.log` — This is where `chkservd` logs its checks.
- `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log` — Sometimes, side effects of server-wide problems may be captured by Apache.
- `/var/log/messages` — On some environments, out-of-memory conditions (OOMs) may be logged here.

### Useful Commands

*These commands can help you identify a server-wide issue as it is happening.*

- `ps faux` — Get a process list
- `killall -9 php php-cgi httpd` — If your server is sluggish due to web requests, this command can be used to recover your server quickly.
- `uptime` — Check the load average on your server.
- `free -m` — Check your RAM usage in mebibytes.  <sup><sub>([Need help interpreting the output?](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/))</sub></sup>
- `vmstat -S M 1` — Watch CPU usage among other useful information.
- `top` — Get a list of the top-running processes.
- `sar` — sysstat logs with CPU usage information
- `sar -q` — sysstat logs with load average information
- `exim -bpc` — If you use Exim and you find that this value is large (over 1000, in general), then you might have a compromised account sending out spam.
- `mysql -e "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;"` — See MySQL running processes.